# Rolify alone or I need CanCan / Authority

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm designing a simple blog system and I'm a rails newbie.

I want to add to my app a role + authorization system, so I'm looking to some combination of CanCan, Rolify or Authority.

At this moment I have separated adminpanel from frontend using namespaces and I create a simple role magamenent: in my admin_controller I check the role and I authorize the access.

```
class AdminController < ApplicationController
  layout 'admin/application'
  before_action :require_logged_admin

  protected

    def require_logged_admin
      unless signed_in? && current_user.can_access_admin?
        flash[:error] = "Only admins can access this section"
        redirect_to root_path
      end
    end
end
```

I need only a couple of roles for admin (admin / editor) and a couple of roles for register user (can comment, cannot comment): can I use only Rolify or I need to add an authorization system? Between CanCan and Authority which is the best solution for an easy implementation (can, cannot)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rolify defines "roles", as you say, an admin, an editor, etc.

CanCan (Authority) allows to connect certain access rights to these roles, access rights that are typically bound to your (CRUD and custom) actions. This way you can specify that an editor can write, while a normal user can only read. In other words you define the relationship between roles - actions - and models/objects. (you can also limit the reading to certain objects, e.g. only the documents the author created himself)

From what you describe in your question, I would suggest to use both Rolify and CanCan. I've been using Rolify in combination with CanCan in several projects. They're a good team for the kind of project you describe!